# Modular: Program calculating percentage discount

Tags: python, python-3.x, program-entry-point, percentage

Create a function called DeterminePrice that will determine the cost of purchased software.  The price is of the software is $350 per license.  However, when purchased in larger quantities a discount is given.  For quantites less than 10 copies, there is no discount.  For quantities greater than 10 and less than and including 20, a 10% discount is given.  For quantities greater than 20 and less than and including 30, a discount of 20% is given.  For quantities greater than 30 and less than and including 40, a discount of 30% is given.  Finally if someone needs to purchase more than 40 copies, a discount of 40% is given.

Your function needs to take in to it the number of quantities the user wishes to purchase.  It needs to return back to main() the discount given and the total cost of the software purchase.

Output and Testing
MyProgramming Lab will call your function.  Therefore, you MUST make sure you name your function DeterminePrice().  Otherwise MyProgramming lab will not be able to locate your function.  Additionally when you write function make sure it first returns discount and then total.  Otherwise your discount and total will not print out correctly.

When your function is run, the output from the first test will look like the following:

```
Enter the number of copies:  35
Discount:  $ 105.00
Total:     $ 8,575.00
```

```
def DeterminePrice(numberOfCopies): 
  discount=0 
  price=numberOfCopies*350 
  if (numberOfCopies <= 10):
    discount=0
  elif(numberOfCopies>10 and numberOfCopies <= 20):
    discount=price*10/100
  elif(numberOfCopies>20 and numberOfCopies <= 30):
    discount=price*20/100
  elif(numberOfCopies>30 and numberOfCopies <= 40):
    discount=price*30/100
  elif(numberOfCopies>40):
    discount=price*40/100
    totalPrice=price-discount
  return discount,totalPrice
  
def main():  
  copies=int(input("Enter the number of copies : "))
  discount,price=DeterminePrice(copies)
print("Discount: $",discount) 
print("Total: $",price)
```

my error says discount is nt defined, but I thought it was under def(DeterminePrice)

Comment: If any solution helped you, please click the "mark as accepted" button. This gives both you and the answerer a reputation bonus, as well as allowing future readers to find the correct solution. There is no obligation to do this, but it is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `discount` is a local variable to your main function.

If you indent your print lines, and make them in main, it will fix the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def DeterminePrice(numberOfCopies):
  discount=0
  price=numberOfCopies*350
  if (numberOfCopies <= 10):
    discount=0
  elif(numberOfCopies>10 and numberOfCopies <= 20):
    discount=price*10/100
  elif(numberOfCopies>20 and numberOfCopies <= 30):
    discount=price*20/100
  elif(numberOfCopies>30 and numberOfCopies <= 40):
    discount=price*30/100
  elif(numberOfCopies>40):
    discount=price*40/100
    totalPrice=price-discount
  return discount,totalPrice

def main():
  copies=int(input("Enter the number of copies : "))
  discount,price=DeterminePrice(copies)
  print("Discount: ${}".format(discount)) #Added print formatting statement
  print("Total: ${}".format(price)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

As a side note, you can do a better looking print statement by using string formatting. See [string formatting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3)

Output:

```
Enter the number of copies : 55
Discount: $ 7700.0
Total: $ 11550.0
```

Comment: Enter the number of copies : 25
Discount: $1750.0
Total: $0

this is the output I receive after

Comment: updated output  using this code:

Enter the number of copies : 25
Discount: $1750.0
Total: $8750

total price is not updating accordingly, discount is not being subtracted

Answer (score -1):

Discount is not in the same scope as what you are calling it in.

You declared Discount in your DeterminePrice Function

```
  def DeterminePrice(numberOfCopies): 
       discount=0 #<-HERE!
       price=numberOfCopies*350
```

Discount is not in the scope of main, only in the function of DeterminePrice

You could make it a global variable, which makes it accessible from inside and outside the scope of the DeterminePrice function

```
def DeterminePrice(numberOfCopies): 
    global discount
    discount=0 
    price=numberOfCopies*350
```

Comment: What benefit comes from making `discount` global? There's an old joke that says the best way to prefix a global variable is with a comment symbol.

Comment: You are on the right track, Perf, in terms of identifying scope of variables.  Global variables are generally to be used sparingly.  Instead, the question contains a key syntax error in three places:  indents.  Indents are key for scoping and blocking.  First, slide the 'totalPrice' assignment left so it is outside the if block.  Next, slide the last two print statements to the right, so they are inside of the main() function.  That should fix things.